# A wagons speed at a certain point of a roller coaster.

Tags: physics

So as an exercise I'm trying solve the speed (m/s) of a wagon on a roller coaster. The wagon is moving at 12m/s at a specific moment and I'm trying to find out the speed of the wagon at 27 meters below the initial position.

The correct answer is 26 m/s but I'm trying to understand how to arrive at that answer.

I'm using the mechanical energy principle function but I can't figure out how to determine the mass of the wagon, all I have managed to cobble together is:  $V_{1}^2$=$V_{0}^2+2gh_{1}-2gh_{2}$ but this just doesn't work.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your calculations. It does work.

Comment: You don't need the mass.  Yes, the change in kinetic energy is the change in potential energy., but both are proportional to the mass.  Depending on what you take for $g$, the answer will not be exactly $26\ m/s$.

Comment: Okay nevermind I'm a tired dumbass. I forgot to apply square root...